# JavaFX animating simon says, cant figure out timing

Tags: animation, time, javafx, wait, pause

Im writing a simon says game in javaFX and i've come across the problem of animating the sequence. I can't figure out how to queue the animation of the buttons(which are arcs that get highlighted)

```
if (mootor.isArvutiKäik()){
                mootor.genereeriuus(); 
                for(int i = 0; i < mootor.getJärjend().size(); i++){
                    if(mootor.getJärjend().get(i)==0){
                        punane.setFill(Color.RED);
                        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
                                Duration.millis(500),
                                ae -> punane.setFill(Color.RED.darker())));
                        timeline.play();
                    } else if (mootor.getJärjend().get(i)==1) {
                        roheline.setFill(Color.GREEN.brighter());
                        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
                                Duration.millis(500),
                                ae -> roheline.setFill(Color.GREEN)));
                        timeline.play();
                    } else if (mootor.getJärjend().get(i)==2) {
                        sinine.setFill(Color.BLUE);
                        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
                                Duration.millis(500),
                                ae -> sinine.setFill(Color.BLUE.darker())));
                        timeline.play();
                    } else {
                        kollane.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
                        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
                                Duration.millis(500),
                                ae -> kollane.setFill(Color.YELLOW.darker())));
                        timeline.play();
                    }
                    PauseTransition test = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(500));
                    test.play();
                }
                //mootor.setArvutiKäik(false);
            }
```

The code generates an integer from 0 to 3 and depending on the integer highlights an arc corresponding to the number. Right now, however, all the generated integers and thus arcs are highlighted at once. 
I saw mentions of platform.runlater (or something similar) but I couldnt figure it out, how to use it.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `Animation` will start as soon as you call the `play` method. Since the loop runs in short time compared to the time the animation should wait, all events happen (almost) simultaneously.

You can use a [`SequentialTransition`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/SequentialTransition.html#SequentialTransition-javafx.animation.Animation...-) to play the `Animation`s sequentially.

The following code demonstrates one way to repeatedly change the color of a `Rectangle`:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(50, 50);

    Button btn = new Button("start");
    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        SequentialTransition sequence = new SequentialTransition();

        List<Color> colors = Arrays.asList(Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW);

        for (Color color : colors) {
            PauseTransition transition = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(500));
            transition.setOnFinished(evt -> rect.setFill(color));
            sequence.getChildren().add(transition);
        }

        sequence.play();
    });


    Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(rect, btn));

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

In your case however you could simply add all `KeyFrame`s to the same `Timeline` animation using different values for the in all `KeyFrame`s. You could simply use `Duration.millis(1000*i + 500)` as the times for the color changes.